# Is it possible to write an action for GitHub that will move some particular columns of a project to another project?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I need to create an automation action in GitHub that will automatically move a project's columns to another project.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an action using the **GitHub API**.

There is a full [project section](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/projects) in the GitHub API with endpoints you could use to customize your action.

There is also already a [GitHub automate project action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/automate-projects) on the GitHub marketplace, that can be used as reference (but that doesn't perform the same thing you want to implement).

Comment: Okay so I need to use GitHub API to achieve it?

Comment: Yes, I don't think it's possible without using it